# Using handlebars 4.7.7 with B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

The MS documentation for the supported version of Handlebars says v4.6.7 (**Runtime**) and v4.7.7 (**Compiler**) are supported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout

I have a custom B2C policy using the latest version of the selfasserted page layout
`<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.10</DataUri>`.

This page is returning v4.6.7 of Handlebars. Our testing has identified an issue with this version and we need to use v4.7.7.

I can't find B2C documentation on how to implement the compiled version for  v4.7.7' using a custom page layout.

Do I need to download handlebars v4.7.7 and reference it in my custom templet page or is there a parameter in the custom policy to enforce the **compiler** version (v4.7.7)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: did you manage to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

We control what is rendered here by the page layout version you select, there is nothing else to configure. Make sure the content definition you are putting the page layout in, is referenced by the self asserted technical profile that’s displaying the page you’re inspecting.

Comment: The documentation states that  v4.6.7 (Runtime) and v4.7.7 (Compiler) are supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout

My pagelayout is returning v4.6.7 as expected based on the layout version number I'm using (2.1.10)
How to I configure B2C policy so the page returns the compiled version (v4.7.7)?

Comment: Correction - I stated the incorrect incorrect version number above - my page is returning the latest 'runtime' version of 4.7.6 . I need to return the compiled version (4.7.7)

Comment: There is nothing further to configure. If it is not the expected result, I suggest raising a support ticket.